# ctx in javascript canvas is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to write something that makes the different iterations of the cantor set. I copied and deleted some of my code and I don't understand why I am getting this undefined error.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<style>
canvas {
    border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body onload="startGame()">

<script>
//var n=10;

function startGame() {
    sheet.start();
   
}

var sheet = {
    canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
    start : function() {
        this.canvas.width = 726;
        this.canvas.height = 680;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
    }
}


    ctx = sheet.context;    
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0,0);
    ctx.lineTo(100,100);
    ctx.stroke();
    

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But I had an example of some code very similar that it won't let me post because it says its mostly code. But some help would be appreciated because this ctx undefined is an error I get a lot and I'm not really sure what it means. I've always used it to draw things on the canvas and never concerned myself with learning what it meant.

Comment: You need to show us your code, we can't debug it by mind-reading.

Comment: It wasn't  letting me post it because it said it was mostly code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Short answer

ctx is undefined because the object `sheet` doesn't have a property called context.

Thus `ctx = sheet.context;` will fail.

## A bit longer answer

With

```
var sheet = {
    canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
    start : function() {
        this.canvas.width = 726;
        this.canvas.height = 680;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
    }
}
```

you're declaring an object with two properties: `canvas` and `start`. As soon as you invoke the start() function on the object, it tries to set the width of it's canvas property to 726 - problem is, sheet doesn't call it's own property canvas before so `document.createElement("canvas")` won't ever execute.

The fix is simple: set canvas to `undefined` initially and create the actual canvas element inside the start function. Nevertheless you still won't have a context property so add it to the sheet object too.

Here's an example:

```js
var sheet = {
  canvas: undefined,
  context: undefined,
  start: function() {
    this.canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    this.canvas.width = 200;
    this.canvas.height = 200;
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
  }
}

sheet.start();

var ctx = sheet.context;
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
ctx.lineTo(100, 100);
ctx.stroke();
```